# 1064, “You have an error in your SQL syntax” inserting in MySql

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas, pycharm

I have the following error on my IDE:

> MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2102@lionstate.edu', '88zlsj5j', 'Kristopher O'Connell', '21', 'F', 'CMPSC', '77' at line 1")

Here is a portion of my code that causes the error:

```
for a, b, c, d, e ,f, g, h in zip(df_stu['Email'], df_stu['Password'], df_stu['Full Name'], df_stu['Age'], df_stu['Gender'], df_stu['Major'], df_stu['Street'], df_stu['Zip']):
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO LSU.Student (Semail, Spassword, Sname, Sage, Sgender, Smajor, Sstreet, Szipcode) "
                   "VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%d', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%d')" % (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h))
```

And This is my CREATE TABLE:

```
cursor.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LSU.Student (
            Semail CHAR(50), 
            Spassword CHAR(20), 
            Sname CHAR(50),
            Sage INT, 
            Sgender CHAR(5), 
            Smajor CHAR(50), 
            Sstreet CHAR(50), 
            Szipcode INT, 
            PRIMARY KEY (Semail))"
)
```

This looks right to me, but the IDE keep saying that there is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is happening because one of the values that you are passing for insert contains a single quote. MySQL cannot tell disambiguate the embedded quote from the surrounding quotes.

```
'Kristopher O'Connell'
```

Here is an alternative syntax using bind parameters, that should work with python:

```
cursor.execute(
    "INSERT INTO LSU.Student 
        (Semail, Spassword, Sname, Sage, Sgender, Smajor, Sstreet, Szipcode)
        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %d, %s, %s, %s, %d)",
        (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h)
)
```

With this syntax, your database driver handles escaping automatically under the hood. This is also a safer syntax, that protects against SQL injection.

NB: depending on the API that you are using, this might also be:

```
cursor.execute(
    "INSERT INTO LSU.Student 
        (Semail, Spassword, Sname, Sage, Sgender, Smajor, Sstreet, Szipcode)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
        (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h)
)
```

Comment: I tried your method, and the IDE shows up a new error:

MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@lionstate.edu,ixg1libp,Alisa Lynch,19,F,CHEM,78 South Brewery Ave. ,62901)' at line 1")

Comment: @pipi: which API are you using? I added another solution.

Comment: I am using PyCharm. I tried your second method, it not works either.   The new error code is     cursor.execute("INSERT INTO LSU.Student (Semail, Spassword, Sname, Sage, Sgender, Smajor, Sstreet, Szipcode) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" % (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: @pipi: the `%` sign in your error message is not part of my answer, can you remove it and see how it works?

Comment: I tried you way first before I added % sign.  The error code is:MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting

Comment: I fixed the problem! Your first solution is right, but when I tried it first time, I added % sign between Value and (a,b,...). That was my fault and thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the `'` off from all the variables inside the values section.

Such as `values (%s, %s, %s .....)` instead of `values ('%s', '%s', ...)`

Comment: I tried this method, the new error code is MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@lionstate.edu,ixg1libp,Alisa Lynch,19,F,CHEM,78 South Brewery Ave. ,62901)' at line 1")